# Binomial coefficient identity

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is there an identity $\sum_{r=0}^{l-1-p} \binom {r}{p}  = \binom{l}{p+1}$ ?
I need a proof for this, if it holds. For $l=2$ I can see that it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather state:
$$ \sum_{r=p}^{m}\binom{r}{p}=\binom{m+1}{p+1},$$
that can be proven by induction on $m$, since:
$$\binom{m+1}{p+1}=\binom{m}{p}+\binom{m}{p+1}.$$

Comment: Is this an equivalent formula ?

Comment: Ok, i think my formula is wrong, it has to be $\sum_{r=p}^{l-1}$.